# Is it be possible to open client's VSCode instance through SSH connection?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am running a home server (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS) and was just wondering if it is possible to open the client's VSCode instance through the SSH connection.

What I mean by is, normally you can open VSCode at the current folder location with the following command line:

```
C:\path\to\the\current\directory> code .
```

And I would like to ask if the same thing can be done with the SSH connection to the server and if so, how I should configure the settings.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an extension in Visual Studio Code can do that for you. It's [Remote SSH](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh)

Here are the steps:

- Install an SSH client. This can be done on Debian-based distribution by using `sudo apt install openssh`.
- Install VSCode (You already have one)
- Install the [Remote Development extension pack](https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/download/extension)

Please refer to the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_connect-to-a-remote-host) for instructions for connecting to your SSH server.

If your SSH server is using key based authentication instead of password authentication, please refer to [this docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_configuring-key-based-authentication)